# spring kafka shutting down producer gracefully during runtime

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-kafka

We have a spring boot application, that uses spring-kafka. We want to disable kafka producer (kafkatemplate), when we update a config property. I have tried with conditional bean, and using applicationcontext refresh.

Is there a way to gracefully shutdown kafkaproducer with spring-kafka ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `destroy()` on the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` and it will close the (singleton) producer, but the next time some code calls `createProducer()` another one will be created; there's currently no way to prevent that. You would need to subclass the factory and throw an exception when you don't want a producer to be created.

Comment: Hi Gary - that would work for our need. destroy() was called and later when message was sent (tried calling createProducer) - we get the following error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send after the producer is closed.
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:172) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:474) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:436) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]

Comment: Don't try to put stuff like that in comments here; it doesn't render well; it's better to edit your question and add a comment to say you have done so. You need to show the full stack trace but I see the `KafkaTemplate` caches the producer; that's wrong; we should fetch the producer from the factory each time. I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/232). As a work-around, you will need to create a new `KafkaTemplate` so it fetches the new producer from the factory.